# Simon Says Python Tkinter Game

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I need to code a Simon Says game using tkinter . The CPU generate random # of first moves and the CPU image changes to the generated listed. The user then uses the button on the GUI window and the clicks are added to a list. Then Both list are compared.

I'm having trouble having the CPU label change image for every move of the generated list. Additionally, I am stuck on how to compare the elements of both list.

```
import random
import time
from tkinter import *

import csv

from PIL import ImageTk, Image


# import vroom_logic
# from logTk import *
# from vroom_logic import *


class Gui:

    def __init__(self, window):
        # Image variables

        self.listofdirect = ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right']
        self.player_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/mavs.png"))
        self.caller_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/durango.png"))
        self.right_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/right.png"))
        self.left_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/‎left.png"))
        self.up_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/‎up.png"))
        self.down_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/‎down.png"))
        self.window = window
        # Caller Frame
        self.frame_one = Frame(self.window)
        self.caller_lbl = Label(self.frame_one, image=self.caller_img, width=180)
        self.score_lbl = Label(self.frame_one, text="Score: ")

        # self.input_name = Entry(self.frame_one, width=20)
        # self.input_name.pack(side='right')
        self.caller_lbl.pack(side='left')
        self.score_lbl.pack(side="top")
        self.frame_one.pack()

        self.frame_one2 = Frame(self.window)  # spacer
        self.label_age = Label(self.frame_one2, width=6)
        self.label_age = Label(self.frame_one2, text="---------", width=6)
        self.label_age.pack(side='left')
        self.frame_one2.pack()

        # Radio Buttons

        # # Student Staff Both
        # self.radio_btn = IntVar()
        # self.radio_btn.set(0)
        # self.radio_stud = Radiobutton(self.radio_buttons, text='Student', variable=self.radio_btn, value=1)
        # self.radio_staff = Radiobutton(self.radio_buttons, text='Staff', variable=self.radio_btn, value=2)
        # self.radio_both = Radiobutton(self.radio_buttons, text='Both', variable=self.radio_btn, value=3)
        # self.label_stat.pack(side='left')
        # self.radio_stud.pack(side='left')
        # self.radio_staff.pack(side='top')
        # self.radio_both.pack(side='bottom')
        # self.radio_buttons.pack()
        # Age Frame
        self.frame_two = Frame(self.window)
        self.user_lbl = Label(self.frame_two, image=self.player_image, width=180)
        self.user_lbl.pack(side='left')
        self.frame_two.pack()
        # Arrow Keys
        self.direct_button = Frame(self.frame_two)
        self.label_stat = Label(self.direct_button, text="Options")
        """Buttons: Up, Down, Left, Right """
        self.upButton = Button(self.direct_button, text="⇧", command=self.upClick)
        self.downButton = Button(self.direct_button, text="⇩", command=self.downClick)
        self.leftButton = Button(self.direct_button, text="⇦", command=self.leftClick)
        self.rightButton = Button(self.direct_button, text="⇨", command=self.rightClick)
        self.upButton.pack(side="top")
        self.downButton.pack(side="bottom")
        self.leftButton.pack(side="left")
        self.rightButton.pack(side="right")
        self.direct_button.pack()
        # Save Button
        self.save_btn = Frame(self.window)
        self.button_save = Button(self.save_btn, text='Save', width=2, command=self.submit)
        self.button_save.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.save_btn.pack()

        self.reset_btn = Frame(self.window)
        self.button_reset = Button(self.reset_btn, command=self.reset)
        self.reset_btn.pack()
        self.button_reset.pack()
        # Direction Label
        self.direct = Frame(self.window)
        self.label_direct = Label(self.direct, text='Please fill out all the values')
        self.label_direct.pack(side='left')
        self.direct.pack()

        self.caller_list = []
        self.player_list = []
        self.DIRECTIONS = ["up", "down", "left", "right"]

        self.MOVE_LENGTH = random.randint(1, 5)
        self.WAIT_TIME = 3
        self.SCORE = 0
        self.ATTEMPT = 0

    def rightClick(self):
        self.user_lbl.config(image=self.right_image)
        self.player_list.append("right")
        return self.player_list

    def leftClick(self):
        self.user_lbl.config(image=self.left_image)
        self.player_list.append("left")
        return self.player_list

    def upClick(self):
        self.user_lbl.config(image=self.up_image)
        self.player_list.append("up")
        return self.player_list

    def downClick(self):
        self.user_lbl.config(image=self.down_image)
        self.player_list.append("down")
        return self.player_list

    def game(self):
        self.computer_list = []
        for i in range(self.MOVE_LENGTH):
            move = random.choice(self.DIRECTIONS)
            # time.sleep(3)
                        if move == "up":
                self.caller_lbl.config(image=self.up_image)
                self.computer_list.append(move)
            elif move == "down":  # down
                self.caller_lbl.config(image=self.down_image)
                self.computer_list.append(move)

            elif move == "left":  # left
                self.caller_lbl.config(image=self.left_image)
                self.computer_list.append(move)

            elif move == "right":  # right
                self.caller_lbl.config(image=self.right_image)
                self.computer_list.append(move)
        # return
        # print(i)
        # self.callerImage()

        print(self.computer_list)
        # self.callerImage()

    def submit(self):
        self.button_save.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.button_reset.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.game()

  def reset(self):
        # self.button_reset.grid_remove()
        self.button_reset.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.button_save.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.player_list = []
        self.caller_list = []
        self.caller_lbl.config(image=self.caller_img)
        self.user_lbl.config(image=self.player_image)
        self.score_lbl.config(text="")
```

Comment: if you want only check if lists are different `if list1 != list2`. If you need to show which elements are different `for a, b in zip(list1, list2): if a != b: ...`

Comment: if you change widgets before ending function - ie. you change image in loop - then you may have to use `window.update()` to force `tkinter` to redraw window. Without `update()` it will redraw window after ending function.

Comment: @Kawinthida Haase. Your code is ok.  If I click (save), do you want `self.caller_lbl` to compare to `self.user_lbl`?